# Limiting distribution $\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i}$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

let $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n$ be random sample of bernoulli distribution with parameter of $\displaystyle\frac{\theta_1}{\theta_1+\theta_2}$ and let $Y_1,Y_2,\ldots,Y_n$ be random sample of geometric distribution with parameter $\theta_1+\theta_2$. If the two samples are independent of each other, how can I calculate the limiting distribution $\displaystyle\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i}$.